# Extracting Common Java Package

Tags: java, eclipse, shared-libraries

I have a project that Contains a bunch of java packages that I have recently understood are needed in a new project that I'm going to develop. I want these two projects to have the same code base so I don't have to update the common libraries in both. How can I achieve this in Exlipse?

my current set up is like this

```
Project1
  CommonPackage
  SpecifictProjectCode1

Project2
  SpecifictProjectCode2
```

I want the following, I think:

```
Project1
  CommonPackage
  SpecifictProjectCode1

Project2
  CommonPackage
  SpecifictProjectCode2

CommonCodeProject
```

What is the best way to achieve this I understand I could extract a jar file or and include it in both project but I want to be able to debug the code and I also want to keep the code editable. Is it perhaps better to extract the code to a separate project and how do I go about doing that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the source code for CommonPackage included as a project within the same Eclipse workspace as Project1 and Project2?

Comment: what you are looking for is to have automated jar packaging and deployment so when ANYTHING in the CommonPackage changes, not only does it get recompiled but its jar gets rebundled with the new binaries and redistributed to whichever other project you have specified it as a dependency.  i think i used to be able to do it in my old job where we had MyEclipse (for which you have to pay) but i am not sure.  i hope it can be done somehow in regular Eclipse.  this is a damn good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have three different projects in Eclipse: `CommonCodeProject`, `Project1` and `Project2`. Then, Project1 and Project2 would have a dependency on `CommonCodeProject`.

To add a dependency on a project in Eclipse, go to `Java Build Path` and add the `CommonCodeProject` in the Projects tab.

Answer (score 2):

Create 3 distinct projects:

- Project1
- Project2
- CommonCodeProject

Go into the eclipse properties of `Project1` > java build path >

choose the `projects` tab and add `CommonCodeProject` project to the dependencies

do the same for `Project2`

both project should now have as dependency your `CommonCodeProject`.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**. Create third project(CommonCodeProject) as Java project and reference that new project in first two projects by navigation below:

```
Project1 -->Properties-->Java Build Path -->projects tab-> Add -->CommonCodeProject
Project2 -->Properties-->Java Build Path -->projects tab-> Add -->CommonCodeProject
```

This should serve your need.

Comment: does it have to be a utility project?

Comment: I updated the answer. I used the word utlity from the `concept perspective` as its common code. Removed it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you would not be editing the common code then make it one project and import as a jar in the other two. or even if you are editing  have 3 separate projects and build common code to create a jar which is used in other two projects

Answer (score 0):

Aside from native Eclipse (as outlined in the other answers), I would use Maven+Eclipse with the [m2e](http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/) plugin (download this using the [Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/)). Depending on the complexity of your project, and it's application, you could even go as far as hosting something like [Sonatype's Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) with your common code deployed to as repository - this might be overkill though.